# How to call methods dynamically based on time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic

I am creating an automatic raffling system. I have a draw button that will run a draw function to select a winner or winners and it sends an email to the admin.

I want this to be a completely automated system so that the admin only has to create the raffles and they receive an email with who won after the draw date has passed. My raffles have a draw date associated with them and once that passes, I need the function to be called.

How do I tell the application to check the time/date to see if any of the raffle draw times have passed? I have looked everywhere and cannot seem to find a way to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow. Where did you search, and what did you find and why didn't that help? Did you write code? If not, why? If so, where is the minimum code that demonstrates a specific problem you encountered? Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Currently your question is broad and is asking for recommendations, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a rake task and add it's execution to your crontab on server. You can use `whenever` gem to simplify crontab scripting and auto update on each deploy (whenever-capistrano/whenever-mina). Example of your rake task:

```
namespace :raffle do

  task :check do
    Raffle.get_winners.each do |w| 
      Mailer.send_win_mail(w).deliver_later  
    end
  end

end
```

`deliver_later` is background execution in queue by the queue driver you use (DelayedJob/Rescue/Backburner etc)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to define a job that runs hourly (or however often you want), checks the draw dates, and runs the draw for any that have passed.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Clockwork](https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork) in my rails apps whenever I need to schedule things. Simply set it up to run a job when you want and do your logic within that job to see which raffles need to be processed. Example:

**Clockwork config**

```
every(1.day, 'Raffle::CheckJob', at: '01:00')
```

**Job**

```
Raffle.not_complete.find_each(batch_size: 10) do |raffle|
  if raffle.has_ended?
    // logic
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will give this a shot. Upon getting the functionality in place, I will post it for future reference for others.